# cannot find HL7 V2.4 xsd for ORM and ORR xsd'd

Tags: hl7

I am looking for the XSD's for the ORM and ORR HL7 2.4 messages.
I've found XSD for other messages, but not ORM and ORR

can someone help pls ?

thanks

Comment: Asking for libraries/documentation is EXPLICITLY off-topic.

Comment: where should it go so ?

Answer (score 0):

HL7.org > Standards

http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=213

This shows schema files for (almost?) all v2 versions

Answer (score 0):

The .xsd files posted on the [HL7 Version 2 Product Suite](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185) page are a bit of a mess right now. Many of them don't even validate. Frank Oemig has been fixing the schema generation VBA code in [The HL7 Comprehensive Database](http://www.oemig.de/HL7/hl7db.htm) and I think he has it working now but the corrected files haven't been posted yet. You might want to contact him directly to see if he can help.